# How to perform artifact-free fast drawing from bitmap data in Cocoa / Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, graphics

Disclaimer: I am mostly experienced with Gtk and FLTK on Linux and Windows.  I am pretty much starting my macOS / Cocoa / Objective-C development journey.  While I have done much research, I am not finding adequate documentation or code examples for this issue.  Also, I suffer from a developmental disability, so please take it easy.

I am trying to draw the contents of a VNC library *(libvncserver / libvncclient)* framebuffer onto an NSView within my program at a fast rate, around 20 to 30 frames a second.  While I am successful at drawing the image onto the NSView at the needed rate, it looks awful with white artifacts all over the place:

[image: Image showing drawing artifacts]

In the NSView's `drawRect` method I first must loop through the framebuffer and set the alpha to 255, otherwise the image will be (mostly) transparent:

```objectivec
  if ([vnc bytesPerPixel] == 2 || [vnc bytesPerPixel] == 4)
  {
    for (int i = ([vnc bytesPerPixel] - 1); i < [vnc buffSize]; i+= [vnc bytesPerPixel])
      vnc.vncClient->frameBuffer[i] = 255;
  }
```

I then make the NSBitmapImageRep:

```objectivec
  NSBitmapImageRep * rep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithBitmapDataPlanes:&vnc.vncClient->frameBuffer
         pixelsWide:vnc.vncClient->width
         pixelsHigh:vnc.vncClient->height
      bitsPerSample:8
    samplesPerPixel:4
           hasAlpha:YES
           isPlanar:NO
     colorSpaceName:NSDeviceRGBColorSpace
        bytesPerRow:vnc.vncClient->width * [vnc bytesPerPixel]
       bitsPerPixel:vnc.vncClient->format.bitsPerPixel
       ];
```

Then I actually do the draw:

```objectivec
  [rep drawInRect:[self bounds] 
          fromRect:NSZeroRect
         operation:NSCompositingOperationCopy 
          fraction:1.0
    respectFlipped:YES
             hints:nil
  ];
```

Since obviously there are other Mac apps out there that can do higher frame-rates without all of the artifacts, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: This is far from an answer because I have no direct experience with it, but is it possible to feed your framebuffer directly to Metal for display? (That would be my first avenue of exploration: avoiding the manual processing required to take the framebuffer, copy it into a bitmap representation, then re-draw it onto the screen; anything that'll let you blit it directly to the GPU will be an order of magnitude faster, if I had to guess.)

Comment: @ItaiFerber Thanks! I will check that out and see if it's an option. Apple's API documentation often has major holes that make it challenging to learn, but the Metal suggestion sounds interesting. 